# Why "change my schedule around", instead of "change my schedule"?

Tags: usage, adverbs, sentence-usage

I heard some people say

> I changed my schedule **around**,

instead of just saying "I changed my schedule." when they, for example, are making college class schedule.

Can I use this expression without "around"? If not, what's the difference between just "change" and "change around"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your schedule around implies that you went and rescheduled several meetings/appointments (presumably to squeeze another one in)

Changing your schedule could imply merely adding a new meeting, dropping a meeting, or adjusting some start/end times.

As an example, if you wanted to have a meeting from 3-4 tomorrow:

If I accept your meeting, no matter what else I do, my schedule has technically *changed*.  If I have to bump other meetings to future dates, or cancel them, or significantly reorganize things to fit you in, I've "changed around" my schedule.

Consequently, "changing around" generally implies a greater sense of importance for this event/meeting than just *changed*.